# Gamified reviewery

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

Stack exchange has a basic gamification structure to encourage constructive behaviour from users. Yet the oversight of that system seems to be a problem at the scale of sites like SO.

Given the [willingness of SE users to play interactive games](https://twitter.com/df07/status/582906770034683904) for internet points, might I suggest something along the [Luis von Ahn's work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx082gDwGcM) on using games to achieve reliable human computation.

Something like "Would Jon Skeet Close This", where the users guess whether a moderator would close a given question. Mix previously-closed questions with undecided questions and you should be able to rapidly address the queue, but play it in pairs so it is still a game and not just a review queue with a timer.

The corollary from von Ahn is of labelling images via the ESP game where you and another user have to type the same word given an image, which results in the question for the user of 'how would someone else describe this image'. Here we want to ask the question 'would a moderator close this question' or 'would a moderator consider this off-topic'.

Because the data gathered from a game is not actually a vote, it can be used to cull the easiest decisions so that actual moderators can concentrate on the questions requiring more attention, without becoming a concrete part of the process.

Comment: Since when is Jon Skeet a moderator?

Comment: Who is Jon Skeet?

Comment: He is just Stack Overflow's best ranked guy at 750k rep... Nothing that good really, just a plain old user like me and you

Comment: Reviews shouldn't be gamified, it will hurt the site. [Take this review for example](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7539773) - I saw it while reviewing, cast a vote, rolled back vandalism on two posts by the author and flagged for mods. So now you know that reviews take a lot of time, attention and care. It's not something where you want the wrong people to participate only for the sake of badges and rep.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that reviewing isn't a game by definition. Of course, we have badges to encourage reviews, but still, reviewing should come from people willing to help the site, not people trying to get as much reputation or badges as they can. Reviewing is not a game.

If you put in game elements into the reviewing process, it might be people click too soon to be the fastest, do the most to be the 'best'. Even if you do just a few reviews, and take the time to do it good, it is better than reviewing 50, just for the sake of points.

Comment: I am looking at addressing the problem of a large review queue using the set of people who are not already reviewing. I think they would be capable of guessing in the majority of cases whether a question would be closed by a moderator. The input is a question, the output is a validation against the available rules. Any straightforward task like that is amenable to some level of gameplay.

Comment: How many reviewers have trouble already making the right decision. If you put in this gaming element, it will be really broken.

Comment: To clarify, I am not suggesting changing any of the current review process, merely adding another line of analysis.

Comment: There is no proof that process is reliable in any way.

Comment: @PhilH Historical evidence has reliably shown that adding gamification elements to the review process *dramatically* decreases quality.  It results in more reviewers, but those reviewers are *much* less likely to review properly.  Worse still, these poor reviewers *drive away the good reviewers*, so the total number of dedicated quality reviewers tends to go *down* when gamification elements are added.  So if your goal is to reduce the number of items in review queues, gamification helps.  If your goal is to improve the quality of the content on the site, you don't want to add gameification.